# CoreData load big data

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, core-data

I would like to hear other options on how to load big data(large number of rows - 100000) from a SQL store with `CoreData` in a user friendly(without blocking the UI) manner on iOS.

Currently I am doing this:

1. Make the fetch on a secondary thread on a managed context named **B** for example
2. Notify the UI thread that the data was loaded
3. Send the `reloadData` message to a `UITableView` to display the new data
4. In the table datasource methods I get the data from the **B** context using the `managedObjectID` and the method `objectWithID` on the context **A** which is the main context or UI context in my case.

Doing this sometimes I feel that is not the best approach so I would like to hear other options from you.

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Why do you need to fetch all 100,000 entries at once? Is your user interface capable of displaying that many items at the same time?

Comment: I want to display those rows not load them in memory all at once.. I allready do this and it works but I would like to see if others have different techniques of doing this.. thanks for your question though

Comment: Please take a look at issue #4 of [objc](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/). They provide an example of importing large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it on the main thread using `NSFetchedResultsController` and set the `batchSize` to a smaller value (e.g. 200)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need change monitoring, set NSDictionaryResultType for retch request. Then you will get NSDictionary and you won't need to fetch objects from context A again.